# Node.js wrapper service

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a Node.js wrapper service like the following using npm request module

```
app.get('/some-url', (req,res) => {
    request.get({
        headers: {'param': 'value'},
        url: "https://some-url.com"
    }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
           console.log(body);
           res.json(body);
       }
    );
});
```

The original service is working, I tested it. But I am getting the value of body `undefined`. As a result, no response. What is the mistake in the way I am doing it? Thank you.

Comment: Is the error null?

Comment: The value is undefined

Comment: I mean the error variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error variable will show you what went wrong. There are sites that block wrapping.
Better use tor-request to avoid tracking, although you might also get blocked.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tor-request

Comment: Yes, I saw the error: `Self signed certificate in certificate chain`. Found another SO link to it.